# lib配下のディレクトリに格納しているファイルを読み込みたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

こんにちは

ruby on rails のapplication.rbに以下を記入して、lib/test/hoge.rbを読み込みたいと考えています。

```
config.enable_dependency_loading = true
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

しかし、上記を記入したところhoge.rbの内容を読み込んでくれません。
下記がファイルの内容とコマンドの実行結果になりますが、どうすれば読み込むようになるでしょうか？

---

```
# hoge.rb
class Hoge
  def hello
    puts "Hoge#hello"
  end
end
```

---

```
# application.rb
module TestApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

---

```
# console
PS C:\work\testApp> bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)

[1] pry(main)> Hoge
NameError: uninitialized constant Hoge
from (pry):1:in `<main>'
```

---

```
PS C:\work\testApp> bundle exec rails runner 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
C:/work/testApp/lib
C:/work/testApp/app/assets
(略)
C:/work/testApp/test/mailers/previews
```

---

rails rの実行結果より対象のtestディレクトリ以下を読み込んでないと推測していますが、具体的な解決策がわからず困っております。
※他のディレクトリを読み込む可能性がありますので、できれば「config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/test)」などを追加せずに1行でまとめたい。

どなたか解決策がわかる方がいらしましたら教えていただけると助かります。
なお各バージョンは
Rails 5.0.2
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x64-mingw32] となります。

~(追記)~
なお、hoge.rbの配置ディレクトリは/lib/test/である必要があり、
呼び出し方は、できれば new Hoge などとやりたいですが、Test::Hogeでも問題はありません。
以上、お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: test ディレクトリ下とのことですので、class Hoge を module Test の中に入れてみては?

Comment: @masm さん`class Hoge`を`module Test`でかこんでみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした...

Comment: すいません、上記は呼び出し方がまずかったようです。今度はLoadError: Unable to autoload constantが出てくるようになりました...呼び出し方は`Test::Hoge`なのですが、書き方がまずいのでしょうか？

Comment: `hoge.rb`は`lib/hoge.rb`なのでしょうか`lib/test/hoge.rb`なのでしょうか。クラスは`Hoge`である必要があるのか、`Test::Hoge`でもよいのか、どうでしょうか。autoloadはクラス名とファイルパスが対応していなければならないので、ここが混乱するとどうしようもありません。やりたいことを正確に書いてください。(コメントではなく質問を追記編集してください)

Comment: @suzukis さん コメントありがとうございます。コメントにていただいた内容を追記いたしました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Railsのautoloadの仕組みを簡単に説明すると、`Foo::Bar`が現れたら、`autoload_paths`に書かれたディレクトリから`foo/bar.rb`を探してrequireします。

`lib/test/hoge.rb`で`Hoge`を定義したいなら、`autoload_paths`には`lib/test`を追加する必要があります。同じファイルを`autoload_paths`に`lib`にした状態で読みたいのであれば、クラスは`Test::Hoge`である必要があります。

パスやクラス名を間違えると失敗しますので、うまく行かない時は

- autoload_pathsの内容
- ファイルのパス
- クラス定義
- 参照しているクラス

をひとつずつ確認してください。

Comment: 詳しく説明していただき、ありがとうございます。おかげさまでより詳しく知ることができました。しばらくはTest::Hogeで呼び出しを行うことにします！

Answer (score -2):

> できれば「config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/test)」などを追加せずに1行でまとめたい。

これだとどうですか？

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: 回答とコメントしていただいたおふた方、ありがとうございました。新しく別のrubyファイルを作成したところ、お二人の方法どちらでもうまく行きました。（何故既存ファイルではLoadErrorが出たのか...?の疑問は残りますが）ひとまずはこのまま開発を進めて行こうと思います。

Comment: Dir[]はディレクトリだけでなくファイルも返しますので、autoload_pathsに大量のゴミを挿入してしまいます。また親子関係にあるディレクトリが再帰的にautoload_pathsに含まれることになるので、ファイルの置き場所やクラス階層を誤った時に意図せぬ動作を引き起こすリスクが高いと思います。